# Sorting while preserving order in python

Tags: python, sorting

What is the best way to sort a list of floats by their value, whiles still keeping record of the initial order.

I.e. sorting a:

```
a=[2.3, 1.23, 3.4, 0.4]
```

returns something like

```
a_sorted = [0.4, 1.23, 2.3, 3.4]
a_order = [4, 2, 1, 3]
```

If you catch my drift.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[1])
[(3, 0.4), (1, 1.23), (0, 2.3), (2, 3.4)]
```

If you need to indexing to start with 1 instead of 0, [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) accepts the second parameter.

Comment: `aorder, asorted = zip(*sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[1])` for completeness.

Comment: I'd be pretty sure, OP would need to zip his two lists back at one stage.

Comment: itemgetter would have been better than lambda

Comment: @dugres: huh? why is that? I'm no fan of lambdas, but if they have a use in python it's here.

Comment: @SilentGhost: itemgetter, also, has many use and this is a good one. **key=itemgetter(1)**

Comment: @dugres: you meant “`operator.itemgetter` *might* be *faster* than `lambda`, although not necessarily in a perceptible way”.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ : It might be faster or not, in this case I don't know, that's not the point here. To me, it's just the reason **itemgetter** exists in the first place ; if you don't use it here, you will never use it.

Answer (score 5):

- Use `enumerate` to generate the sequence numbers.
- Use `sorted` with a `key` to sort by the floats
- Use `zip` to separate out the order from the values

For example:

```
a_order, a_sorted = zip(*sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have `numpy` installed:

```
import numpy
a=[2.3, 1.23, 3.4, 0.4]
a_sorted = numpy.sorted(a)
a_order = numpy.argsort(a)
```

Comment: This is nice for a guy more used to matlab then python =)

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip
a_order, a_sorted = [list(b) for b in izip(*sorted(enumerate(a, 1), key=lambda n: n[1]))]
```